# Add driver using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry-nodes, drivers

**quick version:see the image**

**In short, I'm looking for correct way to use "driver_add("path", index)" to add driver to geometry node input.**

Creating drivers in common modifiers are easy:

For example creating a driver at the width paramater of bevel modifier using the script below.

```py
# Get the object and modifier
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
bevel_mod = cube.modifiers["Bevel"]

# Create a new driver for the Bevel modifier width parameter
driver = bevel_mod.driver_add("width").driver
```

However when facing geometry nodes, **it does not work**.

Because there is "[" after the modifier, rather than ".":

```
GeometryNode Input path: bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"]

Bevel Input path: bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["Bevel"].width
```

I can add driver manually to both modifiers by right click, but I have 88 objects to add driver to.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Add driver to GeometryNodes input

```
import bpy

md = bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]

fc = md.driver_add('["Input_2"]')

# need update the interface manually (place the cursor on the input box)
```

Comment: wow, so simple! Perfectly solved my confusion!